# Unable to locate element unknown error: Element . Other element would receive the click: <div class="loading-wrapper"

Tags: java, selenium, automation, automated-tests

I'm trying to locate the element by XPath: I tried to add wait to load the page and also tried to scroll the page down. but same error

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//text()[contains(.,'Add portfolio')]/ancestor::a[1]")).click();

unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (326, 302). Other element would receive the click: ...

Comment: it different non of answered is worked

Answer (score 0):

1. Add ExplicitWait to wait for the element to be visible/clickable

   ```
    webDriverWait waitForElement = WebDriverWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15));
    waitForElement.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(by));
   ```
2. If there is any overlay that appears, ensure its closed since it might obstruct the element from getting the click

Comment: I tried this yes, same error. it seems another class gets the click.. is there any way to hide the class which get the click as in the error said

Comment: could you provide html or share screenshot at the time of failure?

Comment: it's worked when I added  ...... driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Add portfolio")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);

Answer (score 0):

This might help you but make sure there is no alert or popup active in the window.

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath_of_elm")));
     Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_of_elm"))).click().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use JavascriptExecutor click method here.

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

If this is still not working, then check if there is any loading image there on the screen; you would be required to wait for that image to disappear in that case.